# How to dequeue css files?

Tags: theme-development, wp-register-style

I have bought a theme, but on a particular page i don't want to use the theme js/css files.

The theme registers the files like

```
function add_our_scripts() {
    global $post;

    $options = get_option('radium_theme');

    wp_enqueue_style( 'radium', RADIUM_CSS_URL . '/radium.css', false,'1.0','all'); //the framework stylesheet
    wp_enqueue_style( 'main-style', get_stylesheet_uri(), false,'1.0','all'); //the main stylesheet
    wp_enqueue_style('sliders', RADIUM_CSS_URL . '/sliders.css',false,'1.0','all'); //sliders
    wp_enqueue_style etc
```

and add_action call

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'add_our_scripts',0);
```

full js http://jsfiddle.net/wesweatyoushop/FQrKp/

I created the following remove function

```
    function remove_radium_scripts() {
    echo 'Test check';
    wp_dequeue_style('radium');
    //wp_dequeue_style( array('radiumshortcodes','sliders','radium') );
    //wp_deregister_style( array('radiumshortcodes','sliders','radium') );
}

add_action( 'test_remove_scripts', 'remove_radium_scripts', 999 );
```

And in the header of the specific page i added

```
do_action('test_remove_scripts');
```

I can see the Test check but the radium.css is still there

How can i fix this

Comment: We need a bit more code in order to answer your question. What is the `add_action()` call into which `add_our_scripts()` is hooked?

Comment: @ChipBennett fyi `add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'add_our_scripts',0);` and i already tried `wp_dequeue_script('radium');`

Comment: please **edit your question** to add this detail, so it doesn't get lost in the comments.

Comment: Or, you can add some direct condition with "page id" to skip files that you don't want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Use the correct action hook

Notice the action hook being used:

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'add_our_scripts',0);
```

And the action hook you're defining/using:

```
add_action( 'test_remove_scripts', 'remove_radium_scripts', 999 );
```

You need to hook into the *same action*:

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'remove_radium_scripts', 999 );
```

### Use the correct priority

Notice the `priority` being used:

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'add_our_scripts',0);
```

And the `priority` you're using:

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'remove_radium_scripts', 999 );
```

You need to hook into the *same `priority`*:

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'remove_radium_scripts', 0 );
```

### If all else fails, use last-minute dequeue

If those don't work, you can use a more aggressive option: dequeue at `wp_print_styles`, with a high priority:

```
add_action( 'wp_print_styles', 'remove_radium_scripts', 9999 );
```

Comment: thanks i tried your suggestion with no luck. Not even the following in functions.php `function remove_radium_scripts() {
 echo 'Remove it?: '.time();
 wp_dequeue_script('radium');
}

//add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'remove_radium_scripts', 0 );
add_action( 'wp_print_styles', 'remove_radium_scripts', 9999 );`

Answer (score 0):

All you need to dequeue that stylesheet is:

```
function remove_radium_scripts() {
    wp_dequeue_style('radium');
    //wp_dequeue_style( array('radiumshortcodes','sliders','radium') );
    //wp_deregister_style( array('radiumshortcodes','sliders','radium') );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'remove_radium_scripts', 999 );
```

I don't know exactly where you've added that new action but it is almost certainly going to be too early or too late. Before `wp_head()` is too early, after is too late. You'd have to add your hook on a hook to make that work. Something like this (before `wp_head()`).

```
add_action(
  'wp_head',
  function() {
    do_action('test_remove_scripts'); 
  },
  1,999
);
```

Comment: Why create an action hook just to hook it into an existing action?

Comment: @ChipBennett: Look at the first block of code. That is the solution. The second block is part of the explanation of why the OP's code does not work and what you'd have to do to make it work.

Comment: I understand that the OP created a new action hook. I disagree that such is needed, preferable, or even recommended.

Comment: @ChipBennett: Look at the first block of code-- the block labeled "All you need to dequeue that stylesheet is:" What part of that are you missing?

Comment: Maybe we're saying the same thing?

Comment: @ChioBennet:  Ultimately, I think we are saying the same thing.

Comment: hmm, guys i was planning to make a custom action hook. Which can be called from template headers if needed. By directly hooking into wp_enqueue_scripts i can't call it on specific template headers, right?

Comment: "*By directly hooking into wp_enqueue_scripts i can't call it on specific template headers, right?*" - why not? That's what contextual conditionals are for. Just wrap your `wp_dequeue_style()` call inside of an appropriate conditional, such as `if ( is_page( 'whatever' ) ) { wp_dequeue_style(); }`, *inside* of your callback.

Comment: ^^ @ChipBennett is correct. You should be able to write your conditions into the callback.